# Are these (or similar) examples of Hamiltonians useful in non-relativistic QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

In non-relativistic quantum mechanics the Hamiltonian of an electron in electromagnetic field look
$$H=-\frac{1}{2m}(\hbar\nabla -i\frac{e}{c}\vec A)^2+e\phi.$$
Other known to me examples of Hamiltonians are special cases of this one, e.g. harmonic oscillator. An exception is  the [Pauli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation) which takes spin into account and is a little more general. **I am wondering if there are still more general Hamiltonians which have physical meaning in non-relativistic QM.**

For example one may consider $H=-(q^2+1)\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta$ or $H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta+\vec f(\vec q)\cdot \nabla$, where $\vec f$ is a vector valued function. Do they have any physical significance?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/608961/2451

Comment: Hi MKO. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: That question was closed before I have rewritten it completely. Then I deleted that version and posted this one. I do not know why the previous version is still visible.